# How to get the sum till Kth term of this series for the given N ? I want the formula to get the sum till K'th term in this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Here I have a series
for N=2 -> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and the series continues

for N=3 -> 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6 and the series continues

for N=4 -> 0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5 and the series continues

I have already tried using different formulas but I can't make a definite formula which hold for every given N and K.
The Constraints on N and K are: N ranges from 2 to 10^18 and K ranges from 1 to 10^18

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange ! Please use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is the missing zero in the first sequence intentional, part of another pattern, or just a transmission error?

Comment: Sorry about that, there is a zero at the beginning of each series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have $$K=1+i(N-1)+j,$$ $j\in\{0,1,..,N-2\}$ where $i,j$ can be computed using integer division and remainder. Then the sum is by the basic summation formula of the first integers $0,1,...,i$ and the remaining $j$ instances of the sequence elements $i+1$
$$
(N-1)\frac{i(i+1)}2+j(i+1).
$$

Comment: Can you please explain about the variable I and J and what are their values. I can't understand that, Thanks in advance

Comment: $i=(K-1){\rm div}(N-1)$, $j=(K-1){\rm mod}(N-1)$. I interpreted your task as computing the sum without carrying out the summation of the sequence terms.

Comment: Thanks sir, I got the correct answer. Thanks for responding in such a short time.